# Mocking one method of an object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a class `PhotoOrganiser` and am trying to unit test its method `SortAll`. This method calls another method in the class, `MovePhoto`.

What is the correct way to go about this? Using Moq, I have mocked out the other classes `SortAll` references, but as far as I can see there is no way to mock just one method on an object without mocking the object itself. Is the cleanest way to do this simply to create a new subclass which overrides `MovePhoto`?

Comment: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart ctrl-f for "partial"

Comment: Zerkms is right. The thing you're looking for is **partial mock**. `Moq` supports it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I missed that. Doing that then, I would have to make the methods to override virtual? Is it considered good practise to do so purely for the purpose of testing (as opposed to for use within the program itself)?

Comment: @tsvallender I use partial mocks when necessary. Not sure if it's considered good or bad by community though :-)

Comment: IMO: don't. You're testing the class with its public API like any consumer would, so test the logic accordingly. Do not test "method by method", but by calls/behaviors. Give a shot to TDD, that's exactly what you end up doing.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to mock `MovePhoto`. Your `SortAll` method sounds like it should have easy to assert, observable result (photos being sorted).

I suggest giving your design a second look. Perhaps `PhotoOrganizer` class is too complex? Maybe *moving photo* is large enough piece of work to deserve its own class? Consider what happens when you inline `MovePhoto` usages within `SortAll` method. I realize `PhotoOrganizer` might seem like a good name considering application purpose but in OOP *organizer* might scream [**SRP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violation. Problems with design are usually very quickly highlighted by [hard to write unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24449227/343266).

All things considered you can solve it with partial mock as mentioned by others (and yes, it requires method to be virtual). But this is treating symptoms instead of fighting causes.